# Repair of Sprinkler system

Tags: irrigation

Help? My irrigating system peters out towards the end of the tubing.  All I get is dripping on my last three plants.  What causes that?

Comment: what have done to try to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a number of things. Not enough pressure, a broken line, a missing sprinkler head, plugged sprinkler head, to long of a run.